# Turning text into narrated video in python

Tags: python, video, text-to-speech

I have a lot of text, and I would like to convert it into audio, using some text-to-speech library, and then I would like to turn that audio into a video file, it doesn't matter if the screen is just black, or maybe if the text was the visual?

Anyway, I don't really know where to get started. There is a lot of it, and I need it done a lot of times, and I'm pretty familiar with python but I don't know how I should go about this. Are there standard libraries for turning text into speech for python? Or audio in mp4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no pure text-to-speech engine written in python, but there are plenty of wrappers for other engines. Here's what some quick googling brought up:

If you're on windows, [PySpeech](http://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/) interfaces with the windows text-to-speech engine. It's no longer supported, but may work for you.

There's also an interface for dragon naturally speaking, called [Dragonfly](http://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/). This library also works on the built in Windows system, and is still actively supported.

Finally, if you're on linux, there's [pyFestival](http://code.google.com/p/pyfestival/), which offers bindings for the open source Festival engine.

Answer (score 0):

A bit cheesy, but there is a small hack around this if you have a mac.

Try typing the following in the terminal:

```
$ say 'hello world'
```

And there will be a voice from the mac that will speak that. From python such a thing is relatively easy:

```
import os
os.system("say 'hello world'")
```

Now if you have a screenrecorder on while you are doing this you might have exactly what you want.